# Upgrading to an inactivated version of Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

So there's absolutely nothing that I could find on this, maybe cause it's obvious and I just don't know, but is there a way to upgrade from Windows 7 home premium, to Windows 7 ultimate or pro just inactivated (free method) I don't mind if I need to wipe the drive, I just would like a newer version of Windows, and Windows 10  pro if possible

Comment: If you are using Windows 7 Professional when you Upgrade to windows 10. It will By default it will Go to Windows 10 Pro. If you are using Windows 7 Home Premium then it will be upgraded to Windows 10 Home. Its free. If you are not worried about Data and activation. You can go Clean Installation of windows 10 pro.

Answer (score 0):

You can chose freely from all versions of Windows 10 via the download tool. You will need an USB drive and then you can select any version and language to put on the USB drive. You will of course be prompted to activate/pay for the installed version of Windows 10.

Windows 10 Download tool:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10